# How can I read data from a text file and save/write parts/variables to different text files?

Tags: fortran, text-files, fortran77

I'm fairly new to Fortran so this might be a naive question. I would like to read a huge .txt file with a # of rows=540001. The data are from a sonic anemometer with measurements of velocity and temperature as u,v,w,T at five heights. Here are the first few lines of the file:

```
"2011-07-10 09:30:00",9838,1.132,2.30225,-0.5635,29.18585,0.30275,0.689,-0.01125,29.67004,0.2165,-0.25475,0.12725,29.8923,0.51425,3.0405,-0.58375,29.5242,-0.0085,3.6235,-0.65175,29.61972,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
"2011-07-10 09:30:00.05",9839,-0.21325,3.22775,-0.17,29.10953,0.33925,0.6867501,-0.0015,29.67874,0.1715,-0.196,0.1235,29.8923,0.035,2.6915,-0.3845,29.82806,-0.102,3.5505,-0.15825,29.61795,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
"2011-07-10 09:30:00.1",9840,0.403,3.1195,-0.37175,29.22574,0.06550001,0.6655,0.1275,29.76208,0.196,-0.2,0.1,29.901,0.16225,2.31525,-0.5975,29.69263,0.24175,3.11925,-0.3725,29.57977,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

etc...

I would like to save/write the matrices u(5,540001),v(5,540001),w(5,540001), and T(5,540001) so that I can do some calculations and plots. Here is what I am using:

```
PROGRAM READ_MAIZE
   IMPLICIT NONE

   REAL,DIMENSION(:,:),Allocatable :: u_r, v_r, w_r, T_r

   CHARACTER(len=*) :: fname
   fname='FINALDATA.txt'
   open(unit=1,file=fname,status='old',action='read')

   do i=1,540001
  READ(1,*)timestamp(i),count(i),u_r(5,i),v_r(5,i),w_r(5,i), &
    T_r(5,i),u_r(2,i),v_r(2,i),w_r(2,i),T_r(2,i), &
u_r(1,i),v_r(1,i),w_r(1,i),T_r(1,i), &
    u_r(3,i),v_r(3,i),w_r(3,i),T_r(3,i), &
u_r(4,i),v_r(4,i),w_r(4,i),T_r(4,i),flags(1:20)
   end do
   close(1)

   WRITE(U_maize,'(A,I7.7,A,I7.7,A)'), &
         '.txt'
   open(11,file=U_maize,status='unknown',action='write')
   write(11,'(F20.14)')(u_r)
   end
```

Never mind the order in u_r(5,i) followed by u_r(2,i)... (they just correspond to different heights that are out of order). This is not working.

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Please take care about formatting your post. Use proper tags. Always use tag [tag:fortran] and add specific version where necessary.

Comment: *"This is not working"* does not tell us anything useful. What happens? Any error message? Wrong result? If wrong result, how does it look like?

Comment: You requested Fortran 77, but your code is not Fortran 77 conforming. Your usage of `&` follows free-form source from Fortran 90 and newer.

Comment: The example code is not Fortran 77 (allocatable attribute, free source form, etc.).   Which language revision are you writing to?  The source also contains some basic syntax errors.  Compiler error messages should be pretty specific about these.

Comment: Sorry I copied and adapted this code from a colleague of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a lot going on in your code which makes it hard to understand what you're trying to do in the first place. I have annotated your code below and turned it into something that compiles and produces output. Maybe it'll help.

```
PROGRAM READ_MAIZE
    IMPLICIT NONE   ! This means that every variable has to be declared
                    ! explicitly. You don't do that. So I did it for you

    REAL,DIMENSION(:,:),Allocatable :: u_r, v_r, w_r, T_r
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: data_count  ! using fortran keywords
            ! (such as "count") as variables is dangerous and should be avoided
    character(len=len("2011-07-10 09:30:00.05")), allocatable :: timestamp(:)

    CHARACTER(len=*), parameter :: fname='FINALDATA.txt'
    character(len=len("U_XXXXXXX_XXXXXXX.txt")) :: U_maize
    integer :: in_unit, out_unit    ! Use integer variables for the unit.
                                    ! together with newunit keyword, this is
                                    ! safer
    integer, parameter :: num_records = 3   ! you need to up this number to
                                            ! 540001 again
    integer :: i

    ! If you have allocatable arrays, you need to allocate them before you
    ! can use them
    allocate(u_r(5, num_records))
    allocate(v_r(5, num_records))
    allocate(w_r(5, num_records))
    allocate(T_r(5, num_records))
    allocate(data_count(num_records))
    allocate(timestamp(num_records))

    ! the "newunit" keyword is a safe way to create a unique unit
    ! identifier. You should really use this.
    open(newunit=in_unit,file=fname,status='old',action='read')

    do i=1,num_records
        READ(in_unit,*) timestamp(i), data_count(i),    &
            u_r(5,i),v_r(5,i),w_r(5,i),T_r(5,i),        &
            u_r(2,i),v_r(2,i),w_r(2,i),T_r(2,i),        &
            u_r(1,i),v_r(1,i),w_r(1,i),T_r(1,i),        &
            u_r(3,i),v_r(3,i),w_r(3,i),T_r(3,i),        &
            u_r(4,i),v_r(4,i),w_r(4,i),T_r(4,i)     ! I left out the flags
                                                    ! since I didn't know what
                                                    ! that was.
    end do
    close(in_unit)

    ! I don't know how the file name should be constructed, except
    ! that it should end in a .txt, and the format. So I made something up.
    write(U_maize, '(A, I7.7, A, I7.7, A)') 'U_', 35, '_', 6, '.txt'

    open(newunit=out_unit,file=U_maize,status='unknown',action='write')

    ! To make it more readable, I tell write to write 5 numbers per row,
    ! Not sure whether this is what you want.
    write(out_unit,'(5(X, F20.14))') u_r
    close(out_unit) ! I know it isn't technically needed, but please always
        ! close files when finished, even if the program terminates anyway.
end program READ_MAIZE   ! tell the compiler what you want to end here.
```